# Adverb instead of adjective

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

I read the sentence “Last Christmas I was poorly” and don’t understand why an adverb is used to describe a person instead of the adjective “poor”. Is it an exception?

Comment: Can you provide the excerpt from where you got that? I could be of use for people to correctly answer your question.

Comment: If you look up **poorly** in the [dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/poorly) you will find it is also an adjective, meaning **unwell**.

Comment: It's not ***that*** much of an exception - *a **sickly** child, an **elderly** relative, a **deadly** poison,...*

Comment: Not every adverb ends in "_ly_", not every word ending in "_ly_" is an adverb.